# How to know if a Git repository has submodules before it is cloned?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is it possible to know if a Git repository has submodules before we clone it, and if so what they are and what their URL is?

Also, can submodules have their own submodules, and if so, how many levels of hierarchy does Git permit?

Comment: Recently you asked a lot of questions and received a number of answers. You never accepted one of them as the best answer. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, return to your questions, upvote good answers and accept the best ones.

Comment: I am upvoting the answers, once I have accepted the best I think the question will be closed. Don't we have to wait 3 days before accepting an answer?

Comment: No, they are not. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions Open any question with an accepted answer and see if the question is really closed.

Comment: You do not *have* to wait 3 days, it's just a good idea to wait a bit and try out various answers in case one is better than another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hosting services like Github provide a git repository browser. In the browser we can see the files and folders of a specific commit. If a repository has one or more submodules, it definitely has `.gitmodules`. The names, paths, and urls of submodules are listed in `.gitmodules`.

Some hosting services (not including Github) also allow `git archive --remote` to download specific files.

```
git archive --remote=<url_to_repository> --format=zip master .gitmodules | gunzip -
```

If `.gitmodules` exists on `master` of the repository, the command prints its content. We can check if submodules are listed in it.

A submodule can have its own submodules. The levels are infinitive in theory. A commit records its own submodules only and doesn't know or care if its submodule has any submodule. There could be errors if the checked-out path is too long, which limits the levels in practice.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a perfect answer to this because the presence of submodules is tricky.  [ElpieKay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64135313/1256452), to check for a `.gitmodules` file, is a good method for getting [close enough for all practical purposes](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/2ijugj/a_mathematician_and_an_engineer_agree_to_a/).  I'm just going to get into the weedy part here.

The problem here is that a submodule is represented in a *commit* by an entity that Git calls, internally, a *gitlink*.  A gitlink holds a path name—what Git considers to be a file name, e.g., `path/to/submodule`<sup>1</sup>—and the commit hash ID of some commit in some Git repository.<sup>2</sup>  That lets us dive a bit deeper into your question.

> ... and what their URL is?

This part is tricky because the *initial* URL for a submodule has to come from somewhere, but once the submodule has been `git clone`-ed, Git *no longer cares what the URL is*.  The submodule is now just a Git repository.

The `.gitmodules` file supplies the initial information for a `git clone`, but the `.gitmodules` file is a file, and therefore there is a copy of it in *every commit*.  The copies in each commit *need not agree with each other*.  Perhaps the `.gitmodules` file in commit *X* says to clone github.com/repo1 but the `.gitmodules` file in commit *Y* says to clone github.com/repo2.  Or, perhaps some commits lack a `.gitmodules` file entirely.

One problem in particular is that Git will detect a subdirectory that has its own `.git` repository in it, and when you're in the higher level Git repository, `git add` will simply add that sub-repository as a gitlink entry.  This does not *create* a `.gitmodules` file.  The end result is that people create repositories that "want" a submodule, but lack a `.gitmodules` file, in any commit at all.  When you clone one of these, you just don't get the sub-Git at all.  If that's OK, well, then it's OK.   You can see these gitlinks on some web browsers (such as GitHub's) as a little icon.  [There are a lot of different icons for this.](https://www.google.com/search?q=submodule+icon)

---

<sup>1</sup>Git filenames contain embedded slashes like this.  This is not a folder named `path` containing a folder named `file` containing a gitlink, it's just a gitlink file named `path/to/submodule`.  The reason for this has to go with Git's *index*, which we won't go into here.

<sup>2</sup>With the way that SHA-256 is being introduced into Git, I foresee some problems coming up here.  We may need a new kind of gitlink.

Comment: I see, as long as good practice is followed and we ensure that we do the submodule creation properly, this problem should not occur.

Comment: Right. It's just easy to accidentally create a sort of half-assed submodule: a gitlink without a `.gitmodules`.

Comment: I really did not know this, I can see that Git has a lot of commands. However, most of them are "low level" commands unlike the ones used to do branching and merging and push pulls. Do normal users ever have to actually bother with those type of commands at all?

Comment: Not for most normal use, no. Unfortunately, `git add` is missing an "is there a submodule for this" test. I should look into proposing a fix for that.

Comment: How do users propose fix or improvements to the creators of Git?

Comment: The Git source is public and there's a read-only clone on GitHub (github.com/git/git). There's a process for submitting patches to the Git mailing list, which is also public.

Comment: Where can I find details of this?

Comment: Start by reading the text at the bottom of [github.com/git/git](https://github.com/git/git/) and follow link to the [Submitting Patches](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/SubmittingPatches) page...